# D3 Collapsible Force Layout Mixing up Children and Parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, force-layout

I'm working on the example located on jsfiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R2JGa/14/).

It appears that I have everything structured properly, as the children are properly associated with their parents and the proper text is displayed.

The problems I've run into are as follows...

The main node (in the center) is not collapsible.  The overall behavior of the graph is somewhat glitchy when compared to the example located [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288).

Colors do not change when nodes are collapsed, children of the parent node are displayed when the parent is collapsed.  After several clicks on various nodes, children and parents seem to get switched.

My question is what section of code could be causing this and why?

Here's the code that I'm using to generate the chart.  Data is missing, but is provided by the jsfiddle.  Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
    var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-220)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link");

function update() {
    var nodes = flatten(root);


    var links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

    console.log(nodes);

    // Restart the force layout.
    force.nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .linkDistance(55)
        .start();



    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

    link.enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

    link.exit().remove();

    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes)


    var groups = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("id", function (d) {
        return d.id
    })
        .on('click', click)
        .call(force.drag);


    groups.append("circle")
        .attr("class","node")
        .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("y",-8)
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 4.5 : 10 })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);


    groups.append("text")
        .attr("dx", 12)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        .style("color", "#000000")
        .style("font-family", "Arial")
        .text(function (d) {
        console.log(d);
        return d.name
    });


    node.exit().remove();


    force.on("tick", function () {
        link.attr("x1", function (d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

        node.attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
    });
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
   return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
      : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
      : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update();
  }
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there are two things going on here.

First, by default, d3 uses the index of each datum as its ID (to determine when the item enters/exits the selection).  This is your issue with parent/children moving around, when the element at index X is replaced by a new element, d3 thinks they are the same.  You need to provide a function to return the id:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });
```

Second, you're only setting the fill color of the circle when an item enters the selection.  You should extract the bit that is assigning the style out of the enter() block, so it will be executed each time you call `update()`.

```
node.selectAll('circle').style('fill', color);
```

I copied and hacked together your fiddle into plunker, because jsFiddle was running really slow for me:
http://plnkr.co/edit/7AJlQub6uCGQ3VSvq4pa?p=preview

Comment: Many Thanks redmallard.  I'm new to javascript and it's many supporting libraries.  It's hard enough to figure out basic scripts let alone pick through a new library to figure out how the script is reacting.  Thanks for the clarification.  I was debugging things in the console, but couldn't figure out why the names were being switched around and over written. This did the trick.